# Creating Histograms with R. Questions regarding possibilities of use and problems with overlapping values

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

For my thesis i want to create a histogram on standardized  earnings. This histogram should ideally have the following properties:

- The histogram should be able to have the intervals of the data
  (bins) played with.
- Since i have my data in a spreadsheet. Is it possible to consider
  more than one column?
- Also it should have the ability to set the range of the data that is
  included in the histogram for example from -50 mio. to 200 mio.  (But
  i could do this in my input)

Sadly I was not able to perform this task my own.
I have downloaded the data from orbis in spreadsheet (xlsx). Afterwards I cleaned my data of symbols that R can't read, saved everything as a Tab separated .txt and imported it into R-Studio:

```
 setwd("/path")
getwd()
df<- read.table("importFile", header = TRUE)
View(df)
```

This worked nicely.

Now i tried creating the histogram

```
library(ggplot2)
myplot=ggplot(df, aes(JuStandartisiert2007))
myplot+ stat_count(width = 1000)
```

Then i received the following warning:

```
position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

My histogram looks horrible:

[image: My plot]

This perplexes me, I tried making a histogram on the airquality dataset and it works without problems.

Also note that i have to use stat_count for my histogram in a youtube video i saw, they did it the following way:

```
myplot+ geom_histogram(binwidth = 10)
```

My questions are now:

What is wrong with my Data why i have overlapping x Values? To my naked eye my data looks the same than that from R's airquality dataset.

- How can I sepparate my x values?
- Can i set max and min values for the data that enters my Histogram?
- Can I consider more than one column in my dataset.

Here is my Dataset as TAB separated `txt` file.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jbscj6cftpcqaxh/AADglvv_xnG2wWN-o2SIrTwpa?dl=0

Comment: It looks like your file uses a comma as a decimal separator, where the default is a period. The means most of the columns are read as factors, when it seems like you probably intended them to be numeric. Try passing `dec = ","` to `read.table`.

Comment: ...and maybe you meant `geom_histogram()` rather than `stat_count()`?

Comment: Please provide a CSV (comma separated file)

Comment: Using `geom_histogram()` you get *Error: `width` is deprecated. Do you want `geom_bar()`?*

Comment: @agerom `geom_histogram()` works just fine if you omit the unnecessary width argument.

Comment: library(ggplot2)
myplot=ggplot(df, aes(JuStandartisiert2007))
myplot+ geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01) is working nicely

Comment: now is it possible to combine to data collumms as x values for a histogramm

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I would rather begin with base plotting such as:

```
 hist(df$JuStandartisiert2007,breaks=1000,xlim=c(-2,2))
```

you can also observe the limits for the x-axis.

In order to have the plot of two columns try :
[image]

```
 plot(df$JuStandartisiert2007,df$BilanzsummeAktiva2007,xlim = c(-5,5),ylim=c(-1,1000))
```

Once again observe the x and y limits represented by: xlim and ylim

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To answer 1. i think this will do, but where do i set my Intervalls for the x values.  This cant be the breaks=1000. Regarding question 2 i was asking  for a histogram of two columms. Meaning if i could consider the values of 2 colums in one histogram as x and y still being the frequency of occurrence.